# Editing an existing question or posting a new one - which is better?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question [When visiting the cemetery do we say משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם in the blessing of אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126894/when-visiting-the-cemetery-do-we-say-%d7%9e%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%91-%d7%94%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%97-%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%93-%d7%94%d7%92%d7%a9%d7%9d-in-the-blessing-of-%d7%90%d6%b2/126900#126900) and later answered it: we do not say  משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם after אַתָּה גִבּוֹר לְעוֹלָם אֲדֹנָי מְחַיֵּה מֵתִים אַתָּה רַב לְהוֹשִׁיעַ recited in the cemetery.

The next question is why don't we say it.

Should I post that as a new question or should I rather edit the existing question by adding 5 words to make the question:

When visiting the cemetery do we say משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם in the blessing of אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין - and if not why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're prepared to modify the one existing answer, which you'd written, to answer the expanded question, then I think it would be reasonable for you to expand the question and the answer, as the "what" and "why" questions here are reasonable to deal with together. If not I'd recommend leaving this post alone, posting the follow-up, and cross-referencing.